# Creating Table As substitution

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I am currently working with AWS-Athena and it does not support `CREATE TABLE AS` which is fine so I thought I would approach it by doing `INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY S3://PATH` and then loading from `S3` but apparently that doesn't seem to work either. How would I create a table from a query if both of these options are out the window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon Athena is **read-only**. It cannot be used to create tables in Amazon S3.

However, the output of an Amazon Athena query is stored in Amazon S3 and could be used as input for another query. However, you'd have to know the path of the output.

Amazon Athena is ideal for **individual queries against data stored in Amazon S3**, but is not the best tool for ETL actions, which typically involve transforming data, storing it and then sequentially processing it again.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use INSERT, just create an external table over the location of the previous query results

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/athena-query-results/